# How to deal with multiple jre and a single jar file

Tags: java, operating-system, executable-jar

I am currently working on a java program, but I feel a little bit lost about how to run the jar file on multiple OS which don't have the same jre version.

Let me explain :

- The program I am developing is written in 1.7
- The client need it to work on Mac OS (jre 1.6) and Windows (jre 1.7)
- I generate a .jar executable file using Maven in Eclipse

How can I make it run on his MAC OS and Windows at the same time ?
Is there a way to export the corresponding jre with the jar file ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are a number of distinct questions here.

> The program I am developing is written in 1.7.  The client need it to work on Mac OS (JRE 1.6) and Windows (JRE 1.7)

As a general rule, if a Java application can be compiled for an older platform (e.g. Java 6), then the compiled code *should* run on a newer platform.  But the converse **does not** apply.  There are two main reasons for this.

- The Java `.class` file format is versioned, and a newer JRE can load classes with an older format.  But an older JRE **cannot** load class with a newer format.

  Moreover, the changes to the class file format are made to support new language features.  So if your source code uses features added in (say) Java 7, then you won't be able to compile the code to run on (say) Java 6.
- Each version of Java adds new classes and interfaces to the class library, and adds new methods to existing classes.  If you compile code against the Java 6 SE APIs, then it should be compatible with a Java SE 7 platform.  (All the required classes should be present.)  However, if you compile the code against Java 7 SE APIs, the code may have dependencies on classes and methods that don't exist in Java 6.

In short, if you want your application to run on Java 6, you need to compile it and test it on Java 6.  You also need versions of all of the application's dependencies that are compatible with Java 6.

---

The other aspect of the above question is supporting different operating systems (Mac OS and Windows).  If your application is Pure Java and doesn't have threading problems, it should be OK.  Problems arise if:

- your application depends on platform specific things; e.g. pathname syntax, external commands, native libraries, or
- your application includes native code, or uses `Unsafe` or abstraction breaking reflection, or it depends on JRE internal APIs, or
- your application makes unwarranted assumptions about the thread scheduler, or doesn't strictly follow the rules governing memory visibility (defined in the Java Memory Model), or
- your application uses 3rd-party libraries with any of the above issues.

---

> I generate a .jar executable file using Maven in Eclipse

The way that you generate the JAR file doesn't matter.  What matters is what Java target the code was compiled for and what Java APIs it was compiled against.

---

> Is there a way to export the corresponding JRE with the JAR file ?

Not with Java 6 or Java 7.  The JRE is not part of the JAR file.  For this vintage of Java, the options are to get the client to install a JRE as separate step, OR create an installer that will install both your application and the JRE that it requires.

Java 9 introduced a new utility called `jlink` that will generate a self-contained Java installable from JAR files.  These don't require a separate JRE because they have a cut-down JRE as part of the installable.

---

Finally, a word of advice.  Consider carefully whether supporting a Java 6 customer is really in your long term interest

Both Java 6 and Java 7 are end of life.  Furthermore, many providers of 3rd party libraries have stopped supporting versions prior to Java 8.  This can present serious problems (even show stoppers) if you undertake to support a client who needs Java 6.

In addition, supporting this client will mean that your application codebase will be unable to make use of the new language features and improved APIs in Java 8 and later.  Some of the more important language and API changes are:

- try-with-resources (Java 7)
- Lambdas, method references, type inference, streams and improved date/time handling. (Java 8)
- Modules (Java 9)
- `var` (Java 10)
- Records (Java 15)

This is liable to lead to your codebase becoming increasingly old fashioned, and in need of a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Check the maven-compiler-plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html but keep in mind that if you're using Java 7 features (e.g try-with-resources), the code will fail when your client(1.6) runs it. So I would suggest to use both source and target as 1.6.